# Method missing update_attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, background-process, sidekiq

I have three models:

1. Store (`has_many :products`)
2. Product (`has_many :product_fields` and `belongs_to :store`
3. Product_fields (has a `belongs_to :product`)

I'm using Sidekiq to update a column in product_fields called `content` (When I create the model I insert a url in a column in the same model called second_content so the original content column is null on create, but then I am trying to update the content column in my worker to a new value. Here is my worker:

```
def perform(store_id)
   store = Store.find(store_id)

   store.products.each do |product|
      if product.type_of == "Video"
        video_url = URI.parse product.product_fields[0].second_content
        video = open("LINK HERE").read
        video = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode video

        product.product_fields[0].update_attribute(:content, video)
      end
   end
end
```

and my controller's create action looks like:

```
def create
   @store = Store.new(store_params)
   respond_to do |format|
      if @store.save

          #Start video job
          VideosWorker.perform_async(@store.id)

          format.html { redirect_to @store, notice: 'Store was successfully created.' }
      end
   end
end
```

Everything seems to be working, except in the Sidekiq terminal I get the error:

```
undefined method `update_attribute' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_ProductField:0x0000010531bdd8>
```

Comment: try using `product.product_fields.first.update_attribute(:content, video)` you cannot call `update_attribute` on a `collection_proxy`

Comment: @bjhaid, Thanks for the response, but now I'm getting the error: `can't cast Hash to text`

Comment: `video` is a hash and should be a string, that's why you are getting that error

Comment: @bjhaid, Thanks that worked. Can you add yours as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
product.product_fields.first.update_attribute(:content, video)
```

instead of:

```
product.product_fields[0].update_attribute(:content, video)
```

as you cannot call `update_attribute` on a `CollectionProxy` object also make sure `video` is a string